# Consultar o produto mais vendido

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou com dificuldade de fazer junção de duas tabelas e usar alguma função de agregação, já tentei assim:

```
SELECT nome FROM produto
INNER JOIN vendaproduto SUM(quantidade)
ON produto.idproduto = vendaproduto.idproduto
```

só que está dando erro...

Comment: Seria bom que colocasse o erro que está retornando e se possível um exemplo de como precisa da saída desses dados. No código que você postou faltou colocar o SUM no SELECT e adicionar um GROUP BY: `SELECT nome, SUM(quantidade) FROM produto INNER JOIN vendaproduto ON produto.idproduto = vendaproduto.idproduto GROUP BY nome`. Se não for isso, manda mais detalhes pra facilitar pra comunidade te ajudar :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traduzindo as tabelas `Produto` e `venda_Produto` a partir do seu modelo para `PgSQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE Produto
(
    idproduto INTEGER NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( idproduto )
);

CREATE TABLE venda_Produto
(
    idvenda INTEGER NOT NULL,
    idproduto INTEGER NOT NULL,
    quantidade INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( idvenda, idproduto ),
    FOREIGN KEY (idproduto) REFERENCES Produto (idproduto)
);
```

Cadastrando Produtos:

```
INSERT INTO Produto ( idproduto, nome ) VALUES ( 100, 'Prego' );
INSERT INTO Produto ( idproduto, nome ) VALUES ( 200, 'Parafuso' );
INSERT INTO Produto ( idproduto, nome ) VALUES ( 300, 'Chave de Fenda' );
```

Cadastrando Vendas:

```
INSERT INTO venda_Produto ( idvenda, idproduto, quantidade ) VALUES ( 1, 100, 1 );
INSERT INTO venda_Produto ( idvenda, idproduto, quantidade ) VALUES ( 2, 100, 4 );
INSERT INTO venda_Produto ( idvenda, idproduto, quantidade ) VALUES ( 3, 100, 1 );
INSERT INTO venda_Produto ( idvenda, idproduto, quantidade ) VALUES ( 4, 200, 3 );
INSERT INTO venda_Produto ( idvenda, idproduto, quantidade ) VALUES ( 5, 200, 1 );
INSERT INTO venda_Produto ( idvenda, idproduto, quantidade ) VALUES ( 6, 200, 3 );
INSERT INTO venda_Produto ( idvenda, idproduto, quantidade ) VALUES ( 7, 300, 5 );
INSERT INTO venda_Produto ( idvenda, idproduto, quantidade ) VALUES ( 8, 300, 5 );
```

Para se determinar qual foi o produto mais vendido, você pode combinar a função de agregação `SUM()` com as cláusulas `ORDER BY` e `LIMIT`, veja só:

```
SELECT
  idproduto,
  sum(quantidade) AS qtd_total
FROM
  venda_Produto
GROUP BY
  idproduto
ORDER BY
  qtd_total DESC
LIMIT
  1;
```

Saída:

```
| idproduto | qtd_total |
|-----------|-----------|
|       300 |        10 |
```

Agora, incluindo o `JOIN` com a tabela de `Produtos`:

```
SELECT
  vp.idproduto,
  p.nome,
  sum(vp.quantidade) AS qtd_total
FROM
  venda_Produto AS vp
JOIN
  Produto AS p ON ( p.idproduto = vp.idproduto )
GROUP BY
  vp.idproduto,
  p.nome
ORDER BY
  qtd_total DESC
LIMIT
  1;
```

Saída:

```
| idproduto |           nome | qtd_total |
|-----------|----------------|-----------|
|       300 | Chave de Fenda |        10 |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c3224f/4)